# Codeception geolocation

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, geolocation, codeception

I am getting geolocation with javascript with

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(..
```

Is there any chance in Codeception a test value can be given for this? I cannot find anything on this, except for settings in Selenium which would make the test not independent from the Selenium server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test anything that is javascript with Codeception, except if you use Selenium. Codeception is a good tool to test PHP apps with a little bit of JS used for the needs of the view but not for full JS funcs testing.
For this, you could use other JS testing frameworks like UnitJS or else.